# Does Volley create a new network connection for every request in Request Queue?

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking

I am using Volley as my networking library for my Android project. I'm curious to know when is a network connection opened and if Volley maintains the same connection when executing multiple POST requests using same request URL?

Comment: As mentioned here https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html, Volley uses different network connection for each post request you make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the `HttpStack`interface implementation. Volley has two out of the box - the `HurlStack` that uses `HttpUrlConnection` and `HttpClientStack` that uses the Apache library.

A quick look at `HurlStack` shows that a new `HttpUrlConnection` object is created per request. Normally, connection pooling and reuse is handled by the `HttpUrlConnection` itself. I think that it will behave as smartly as possible and reuse as much resources as possible.

The same applies for the `HttpClientStack`. It uses a shared `HttpClient` to perform requests, so it's up to Apache's library to deal with connection pooling, etc.

To summarise, low-level network creation and maintenance is not something with which Volley deals directly. It's all a question of specific implementations, but, as far as I can remember, they will do as much of the heavy lifting for you as possible.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I found the same thing while browsing through Volley's implementation code.